# StackOverflowError when persisting entities with bidirectional relation

Tags: persistence, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have two kinds of entities with a bidirectional ManyToMany relation between them. I don't want to post their structure here, because I don't think it would help. Any changes in that relation didn't help, however the relation ist annotated as follows

```
// relation in the first entity class
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "Entity1_Entity2",
                joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "entity1") },
                inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "entity2") })
private List<Entity2> subEntities = new ArrayList<>();

// relation in the second entity class
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "relatedEntities", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Entity1> owningEntities = new ArrayList<>();
```

So there are possibly circular dependencies. But as far as I know EclipseLink as well as most other JPA implementations can manage this. However while the persisting of few related entities works wothout problems, I get a StackOverflowError when there are too much of them:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.extractPrimaryKeyFromObject(ObjectBuilder.java:3011)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.getCacheKeyFromTargetSessionForMerge(AbstractSession.java:2702)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.getTargetVersionOfSourceObject(MergeManager.java:196)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ContainerPolicy.createWrappedObjectFromExistingWrappedObject(ContainerPolicy.java:728)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.mergeIntoObject(CollectionMapping.java:1648)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4132)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeChangesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4065)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:839)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:698)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:309)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.mergeIntoObject(CollectionMapping.java:1638)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4132)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeChangesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4065)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:839)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:698)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:309)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.mergeIntoObject(CollectionMapping.java:1638)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4132)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.mergeChangesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:4065)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:839)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfWorkingCopyIntoOriginal(MergeManager.java:698)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:309)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.mergeIntoObject(CollectionMapping.java:1638)
...
```

I already removed cascaded persisting as you can see in the annotations above as I could imagine that this caused the depth of recursion. But again I got this error. When I increase the allowed stack it works again, but in my opinion the problem isn't solved then. But it tells me that the recursion isn't endless. Also the error only occurs because of the bidirectional relation because is isn't thrown when i make it unidirectional.
So the questions are: Why is the recursion depth increased when more entities are persisted? And how can this be avoided without making the relation unidirectional?

Comment: Does it compile at all? List and HashSet are not compatible.

Comment: Oops... No, of course you are right and it wouldn't compile, that was a typing mistake. It's correct now